# What is the .NET equivalent of Java's java.util.concurrent package?

Tags: java, .net, concurrency

I come from a Java background. I am wanting to learn more about concurrency in .Net and C#. Is there something similar to Java's concurrent utils package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest will be the new threading abilities in .NET 4.0, also known as Parallel Extensions.

The existing capabilities of .NET (i.e. in 3.5 and earlier) are better than Java *without* java.util.concurrent, but it certainly doesn't cover everything which *is* in java.util.concurrent.

The [Parallel Extensions Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam) is well worth reading to learn more.

Comment: Thank you. This might be what I am looking for. I would like to learn to write really high performance concurrent code in C#. I would know how in Java but would like to port that knowledge to .Net. Just because I feel that the Java language (as much as I like it) is getting left behind.

Comment: Parallel Extensions is definitely what you want to be looking at then. You might also want to investigate the CCR for a bit of fun: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163556.aspx

Comment: Perfect thanks. I am sure this and maybe a book or two is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the stuff you will be interested in is probably in the [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace.

.NET 4.0 has some very interesting extensions called [ParallelFX](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/) that looks really promising as well.

Answer (score 0):

namespace: [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx)
It has thread-safe blocking type collections.
Some of them are,

- [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [BlockingCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)