# .Net equivalent to java.util.concurrent.Executor

Tags: c#, .net

After looking some questions:

- [What is the .NET equivalent of Java's java.util.concurrent package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820418/what-is-the-net-equivalent-of-javas-java-util-concurrent-package)
- [Is there a .Net equivalent to java.util.concurrent.Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928018/is-there-a-net-equivalent-to-java-util-concurrent-executor)
- [C# equivalent for Java ExecutorService.newSingleThreadExecutor(), or: how to serialize mulithreaded access to a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661760/c-sharp-equivalent-for-java-executorservice-newsinglethreadexecutor-or-how-t)

They are not I want.

The max worker thread count is limited (`ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads`).

When I use `Task.Run()` API,
**after put toooooooo many low priority level task, I cannot execute a high priority level task immediately.**.

Any idea without create my own task queue?

(In java or python, I can use two Executor to do this.)

Comment: I would start with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2210128/27358).

Comment: @DavidMoles Task Parallel Library use `TaskScheduler.Default` as task scheduler, `TaskScheduler.Default` is `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, it call thread pool direct. It  is same as `Task.Run()` API.

Comment: @DavidMoles Seem like I have to create my own Custom Scheduler.